# entry and close on same bar causing error Uncaught Error: Value is null

Tags: pine-script

[image]

video --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/F46yk.jpg

### **Issue**

The below code will throw the following error: Uncaught Error: Value is null.

It happens when the entry and close occur on the same bar and **only in real time**. This is on the 1m chart.

Per the photo, on candle 1 and 2, as soon as an exit happened, those errors started happening and the chart went blank. All I saw was the candles. After a minute or on the next bar everything came back.

### **Expected Behavior**

To be able to buy and sell on the same bar with no problems.

### **Code**

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Real-time set up", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true, pyramiding=0, currency="USD", initial_capital=5000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)

// helpers
convertToTicks(num) => num / syminfo.mintick
convertTicksToClose(num) => num * syminfo.mintick
getProfitAndLossTargets(p, l) => 
    pt = p / 100
    lt = l / 100
    testProfitTargetTicks = convertToTicks(close * (1 + pt))
    testProfitTarget = convertTicksToClose(testProfitTargetTicks)
    testLossTargetTicks = convertToTicks(close * (1 - lt))
    testLossTarget = convertTicksToClose(testLossTargetTicks)
    [testProfitTarget, testLossTarget]

inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2021, 6, 8, 0, 0))
isAnOpenTrade = strategy.opentrades == 0 ? false : true

varip profitTarget = 0.0
varip stopTarget = 0.0
varip int posCloseTime = time

bars_elapsed = 2 * 60000 // 2 bars

if inDateRange and (time - posCloseTime) > bars_elapsed
    if isAnOpenTrade == false
        [profit, stop] = getProfitAndLossTargets(.1, .1) // 1 equals 1%
        profitTarget := profit
        stopTarget := stop
        strategy.entry("xx", strategy.long, comment="Test Entry")
    
    else if isAnOpenTrade and close >= profitTarget
        posCloseTime := time
        strategy.close("xx", strategy.long, comment="Test Profit")
        
    else if isAnOpenTrade and close <= stopTarget
        posCloseTime := time
        strategy.close("xx", strategy.long, comment="Test Stop Loss")
        
        
plot(profitTarget, title="profit", color=color.green)
plot(stopTarget, title="loss", color=color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the kind of cool down you want. Store the time when you exit and evaluate as a condition of the next entry.

```
var int posCloseTime = time

if inDateRange and time - posCloseTime >= 900000
    if isAnOpenTrade == false
        strategy.entry("xx", strategy.long, comment="Test Entry")
    
    else if isAnOpenTrade and close >= close[10]
        posCloseTime := time
        strategy.close("xx", strategy.long, comment="Test Profit")
        
    else if isAnOpenTrade and close <= close[10]
        posCloseTime := time
        strategy.close("xx", strategy.long, comment="Test Stop Loss")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. It seems that your cool-down approach does work. I've updated the original post with a photo, updated code example, and description of the error which hasn't gone away.

Please keep in mind that this is in real time (calc_on_every_tick=true). So once a buy occurs, if a sell occurs on the same bar you'll see the error in the console and the chart sort of blows up. Not sure why... Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately is seems it's a known bug and the fix is under development